# What is the configuration for setting up MySQL workbench with a AWS Bitnami instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, bitnami

I am some issue with connecting the pipes between MySQL Workbench and my Bitnami Wordpress instance on AWS (using ssh). I have read and attempted the docs several times, I don't know what is going on.

I have successfully ssh-ed via the command line using `ssh -i my_key_file bitnami@IP-Address`.

However, I cannot get it to work for MySQL Workbench.

```
Field             Value
```

```
SSH Hostname        IP-Address   
SSH Username        bitnami
SSH Key File        <path-to-key-file>   
MySQL Hostname      127.0.0.1   
MySQL Server Port   3306   
MySQL username      root
```

The path to key-file is correct as it works for other AWS instances. And the `SSH hostname` and `SSH username` get my access via the terminal - so I would assume these are fine?

When I test the connection, I am prompted for a password. Everywhere online suggests that this password is the admin password used the Wordpress account (accessible via the system logs). I have this password. However, this doesn't get me in.

The attempted connection returns the error: **Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 through SSH tunnel at bitnami@IP-Address with user root**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read and attempted the docs several times, I don't know what is going on.

I guess you are referring to this [documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/mysql/#how-to-configure-mysql-workbench)

Could you try to reset the password for the root user as described in the guide below?

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/mysql/#how-to-reset-the-mysql-root-password

Once you have restarted it and you have chosen a new one, use this new password on the Workbench.

Comment: Although I tried the reset before, this seems to sort it thanks. Perhaps I missed something! Thanks for the prompt!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :)